# I don't know how to make my <ol> inside <ul> begin with only one number

Tags: css, html-lists, css-counter

I'm trying to style lists inside of lists in CSS but there is a problem when I have an ordered list inside an unordered one. I'd like the ordered list which is inside an unorered list to begin at 1. and not at 6.1 and I don't know how to do it. Does someone know an easy way to do this ? I don't really understand how the counter behaves in this case.

### HTML

```
<ol>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
        <ol>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
        <ul>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
    </ol>
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
        <ol>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
        <ol>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
    </ul>
```

### SCSS

```
ul {
  &>li {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 4rem;
    &::before {
      content: "\2022";
      color: charte.$primaryColor;
      font-size: 4rem;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;    
    }
  }
}

ol {
  counter-reset: item;
  &>li {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 4rem;
    &::before {
      counter-increment: item;
      content: counters(item, ".") ".";
      font-weight: 700;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

### Result

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptraj.png)

Comment: Please edit your question and use the snippet tool `<>` to load your html and css

Answer (score 0):

Normal HTML code meets your expectation without SCSS. Use SCSS only for styling list items and don't make counting in it.

```html
<ol>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
          <ol>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
          </ol>
        </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
          <ul>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
      </ol>
      <ul>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
          <ol>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
          </ol>
        </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
          <ol>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
          </ol>
        </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
      </ul>
    </ol>
```

You can style list items with appropriate CSS properties